# Android different color border colour in linearlayout by code

Tags: android, layout

I want to draw linearlayout border with different color by Java code, not using xml file

if that's possible? Please give me code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution of that problem, if you found please share the solution

Answer (score 1):

For Android, the LinearLayout layout does not come with a border attribute. You can however, set the background of the LinearLayout to a 9 patch image.

You can modify anything on the xml file you're creating as long as you link it back to your Java file.

Example: 
If your xml file was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- note that the id is linearlayout. That's important, you want the id to be something you can use to identify that element. -->
<LinearLayout`
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Java file you'd have to do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whateverXMLFile);

    //get the Linear Layout you're searching for 
    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

    /*background is your background image you want to replace with. 
     * You can use any that is in your drawable resource. 
     * Better to use a 9 sketch because it'll expand to fit your width/height, no matter
     * how big or small your layout will be. 
     */
    linLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);


    //if you want to set the background colour: 
    //will set it to RED, you can also specify a resource file you may have for it 
    linLayout.setBackground(Colour.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a nine-patch image and set the background.

Comment: I don't want to use images, I want use color

Comment: Then you can create a ShapeDrawable and change the stroke color.